# how to get the text using preceding and following sibling using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

input xml:

```
<article>

<sb:title>

<sb:maintitle>

 An 

 <mml:math>

   R

 <superscript>

   4

 </superscript>

 </mml:math>

 spacetime with a Cauchy surface which is not 

 <mml:math>

   R

 <superscript>

   3

</superscript>

</mml:math>

</sb:maintitle>

</sb:title>

</article>
```

expected output xml:

```
<article>
               <sb:title>

                    <sb:maintitle>

                       An

                        <mml:math>

                            <mml:msup>

                                <mml:mrow>

                                    <mml:mi>R</mml:mi>

                                </mml:mrow>

                                <mml:mrow>

                                    <mml:mn>4</mml:mn>

                                </mml:mrow>

                            </mml:msup>

                        </mml:math> 

                       spacetime with a Cauchy surface which is not 

                        <mml:math>

                            <mml:msup>

                                <mml:mrow>

                                    <mml:mi>R</mml:mi>

                                </mml:mrow>

                                <mml:mrow>

                                    <mml:mn>3</mml:mn>

                                </mml:mrow>

                            </mml:msup>

                        </mml:math>

                    </sb:maintitle>

                </sb:title>

</article>
```

so far i am using this xslt:

```
<article>

 <xsl:apply-templates select="child::article/sb:title/sb:maintitle/mml:math"/>

</article>




<xsl:template match="child::article/sb:title/sb:maintitle/mml:math">

 <mml:math>

<mml:msup>

<mml:mrow><xsl:value-of select="?"/></mml:mrow>

<mml:mrow><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(superscript)"/></mml:mrow>

</mml:msup>

</mml:math>

</xsl:template>
```

i get second mml:mrow value using superscript. but i dont know how to get first mml:row value?

dont change apply templates;and  what i have to write in my xsl(mml:mrow) instead of "?".

can anyone help me?

Comment: It would help a lot if you improved the formatting of your question to remove the blank lines through-out the code, and to make sure everything is indented more consistently. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you want to transform only a portion of the XML to something else, you are usually better off starting with the [identity template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) which will copy nodes across as-is

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This means you only need to write templates for the nodes you do wish to transform. In this case, it looks like you are transforming `mml:math` elements which have a `superscript` element as a child. So, the template match would look like this:

```
 <xsl:template match="mml:math[superscript]">
```

To output the first `mmrow`, you just need to get the first `text()` node, like so:

```
<mml:mrow>
   <mml:mi><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></mml:mi>
</mml:mrow>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:sb="sb" xmlns:mml="mml">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mml:math[superscript]">
        <mml:math>
            <mml:msup>
                <mml:mrow>
                    <mml:mi><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></mml:mi>
                </mml:mrow>
                <mml:mrow>
                    <mml:mn><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(superscript)"/></mml:mn>
                </mml:mrow>
            </mml:msup>
        </mml:math>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this XML

```
<article xmlns:sb="sb" xmlns:mml="mml">
    <sb:title>
        <sb:maintitle>
            An 
            <mml:math>
               R
                <superscript>
                    4
                </superscript>
            </mml:math>
            spacetime with a Cauchy surface which is not 
            <mml:math>
                R
                <superscript>
                    3
                </superscript>
            </mml:math>
        </sb:maintitle>
    </sb:title>
</article>
```

Then the following is output

```
<article xmlns:sb="sb" xmlns:mml="mml">
    <sb:title>
        <sb:maintitle>
            An 
            <mml:math>
            <mml:msup>
               <mml:mrow>
                  <mml:mi>R</mml:mi>
               </mml:mrow>
               <mml:mrow>
                  <mml:mn>4</mml:mn>
               </mml:mrow>
            </mml:msup>
         </mml:math>
            spacetime with a Cauchy surface which is not 
         <mml:math>
            <mml:msup>
               <mml:mrow>
                 <mml:mi>R</mml:mi>
               </mml:mrow>
               <mml:mrow>
                  <mml:mn>3</mml:mn>
               </mml:mrow>
            </mml:msup>
         </mml:math>
        </sb:maintitle>
    </sb:title>
</article>
```

Note that I've had to make up some namespaces, as they were not shown in your original question.

Comment: thank u very much. it really works fine. i have put another condition for  mml:math also. that one also work with that. how can i remove this. i.e is there any function not selecting mml:math other than superscript child. ex:not(mml:math[superscript])

Comment: If you want to select a `mml:math` that does not have a `superscript` child, do `<xsl:template match="mml:math[not(superscript)]" />`